# Placed Feature giving error: Unbound values in registry ResourceKey

Tags: json, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm making a Forge mod for 1.19.4 that adds a new type of tree and when adding a placed feature so that it can spawn in the world, the client crashed and logged the following error:
`.IllegalStateException: Unbound values in registry ResourceKey[minecraft:root / minecraft:worldgen/placed_feature]: [minecraft:divine_placed]`
I'm unsure as to why it sends this error, as I can't see an immediate issue with the json file as far as I can tell. 
Here is the json file for the placed feature.

```
{
  "feature": "pantheonic:divine",
  "placement": [
    {
      "type": "minecraft:count",
      "count": {
        "type": "minecraft:weighted_list",
        "distribution": [
          {
            "data": 3,
            "weight": 9
          },
          {
            "data": 5,
            "weight": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "minecraft:in_square"
    },
    {
      "type": "minecraft:surface_water_depth_filter",
      "max_water_depth": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "minecraft:heightmap",
      "heightmap": "OCEAN_FLOOR"
    },
    {
      "type": "minecraft:biome"
    },
    {
      "type": "minecraft:block_predicate_filter",
      "predicate": {
        "type": "minecraft:would_survive",
        "state": {
          "Name": "pantheonic:divine_sapling",
          "Properties": {
            "stage": "0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I had forgotten to make the "feature" value in the biome modifier use the "pantheonic" namespace instead of "minecraft", so the game was trying to read the placed feature from Minecraft's code instead of my mod.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).